# Datadog APM traces - how to debug when invocation time is a small fraction of total lambda time?

Tags: performance, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, datadog

I've recently been working on adding datadog function level traces to AWS lambda functions (using the `dd-trace` library), but ended up in a bit of an ironic situation where the instrumentation of said functions has resulted in a performance regression, that makes these changes unable to actually be deployed into production due to how drastically performance is impacted.

In the image below, the invocation for a given lambda is `120ms`, and yet the lambda itself runs for `1.34s` the purple bar of the same colour, right above the one being hovered over). When looking at the logs though, the actual lambda handler code is complete at that `120ms` mark - and the built in lambda logs saying `END REQUEST` doesn't show up until the `1.34s` mark, with absolutely nothing logged between the end of the relevant handler code, and that `1.34s` window.

This has left me stumped on where that black hole of time is (before adding any of the dd-trace code, these gaps were *much* smaller, but never completely non-existent. Any tips on how to debug where those gaps from, and ultimately eliminate them, would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Datadog Trace]
[image: Datadog Trace]